# Emacs + yasnippets performance issues

Tags: ios, performance, emacs

I'm trying to set up emacs for iOS development (as described here: http://roupam.github.io/). The part of most interest to me is using YASnippets and auto-complete to do method name and parameter completion based on the library/framework documentation.

All is working, but performance on my 2.53 GHz, 4GB MacBook Pro is not really usable. It typically takes ~5sec between typing the start of a method name and getting a dropdown of completions. To make matters worse, it grabs the keyboard after two key strokes and prevents further typing while it searches.

Is there something simple that I'm doing wrong? The relevant part of my .emacs setup looks like this:

```
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(require 'auto-complete-config)

(setq-default ac-sources '(ac-source-yasnippet ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
(add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'ac-common-setup)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'objc-mode)
```

Comment: If I remember right then there is a known problem with the performance of packages hooking at `post-command-hook` under iOS. The solution there is to introduce lazy evaluation for the hook-functions (e.g., with a timer). This would require hacking the package in question (e.g., with `defadvice`). I do not work with iOS. Therefore, testing is difficult for me.

Comment: Thanks, Tobias, but Emacs is not running on iOS. I'm running on a Mac -- doing development for iOS.